# null and [], are they not supposed to be the same?

Tags: arrays, struct, null, d

I have modified `std.array.array` so that it will always work at compile time, and it looks like this:

```
ForeachType!Range[] array(Range)(Range r)
if (isIterable!Range && !isNarrowString!Range)
{
  auto a = appender!(ForeachType!Range[])();
  foreach (e; r)
  {
    a.put(e);
  }
  return a.data;
}
```

And a usage:

```
struct Type
{
  int[] xs;
  this(int[] r) { this.xs = r.array; }
}

enum Type t1 = Type([]);
static if (t1.xs.length) { }  // Error: expression null.length is not constant
```

Base on my understanding, when `r` is an empty range, `array()` returns a `null`.  In this regard, is there supposed to be a difference between `null` and an empty array?

Replacing `return a.data;` in `array()` with `return a.data.length ? a.data : [];` does fix the problem, so I suppose there is a difference?

The thing is that this only happens with constructors.  The following doesn't produce the error:

```
enum int[] t1 = iota(0,0).array;
static if (t1.length) { }
```

So I suppose there is no difference between `null` and `[]`?  I'm confused.

Comment: I think it has to do with `r.ptr` being null

Answer (score 4, accepted):

It's true that`[]` compares equal to `null`. `[] == null` and `[] is null` are both `true`. The same goes for an unitialized array or one initialized with `null`.

However, an empty array is *not* always `null`. For example:

```
int[] a;
assert(a is null);
a = new int[2];
a = a[0..0];
assert(a !is null);
```

See *The D Programming Language*, p. 95.

**Edit:**
In light of the fact that compile-time `.length` seems to be malfunctioning, I suggest using `std.array.empty` for the check, which should be more reliable than a `null` comparison. On DMD 2.061, `static if (!t1.xs.empty) { }` works where `static if (t1.xs.length) { }` failed.

Comment: So there are two kinds of empty arrays, one that's null and the other not null?  That's probably a bug.

Comment: It's confusing, but not a bug, since it's mentioned explicitly in TDPL. My understanding is that the `.init` property of dynamic arrays is `null`, as they are a reference type. So the `.ptr` of the array has no other sensible position to be in. After some data has been assigned, `.ptr` points elsewhere, regardless of the array's size. So it's not something you should rely on when testing for an empty array.

Comment: @Arlen Whether an array is empty or not depends on whether its `length` property is `0`. Whether it's `null` or not depends on its `ptr` property (though all `null` arrays will have a `length` of `0`).  So, you can easily have an empty array which is non-null. I highly recommend reading the article that roysc linked to. That being said, I'm not sure why you're getting the error that you're getting.

Comment: @JonathanMDavis The article is nothing new to me; besides, it doesn't even explain `[]`, and neither does p. 95 of TDPL.  Nor do they explain how arrays are supposed to behave in regards to manifest constants.  If `null` and `[]` are the same then there is a bug somewhere, because my code clearly demonstrates that `null` and `[]` are NOT the same.  Are we expected to introduce an `if` statement every time we want to return an array?  My code is asking the real question.

Comment: @roysc What's new to me is that using the `.length` property is not a reliable method for checking to see if an array is empty or not.  This is probably another hint that there is a bug somewhere in DMD.  If you add `static if (t1.xs !is null) {}` to your answer as a solution to my code, then I will accept your answer.  It eliminates the need for the condition operator.

Comment: @Arlen At one point in time, `[]` was not `null` (though it doesn't appear to now), but I don't believe that there has ever been any kind of guarantee as to whether it would be `null` or not. It could be the same as `null`, but it isn't necessarily. Regardless, the fact that `length` would work at compile time with one and not the other is a bit odd and definitely seems like a bug. `length` should be the same for both. It's the `ptr` property that may differ.

Comment: @Arlen I agree with Jonathan M Davis that this smells like a bug, from what little I know. Also, I'd hesitate to suggest using a `null` comparison in that context, because it's not a guaranteed or necessarily reliable behavior. My best idea is to use `std.array.empty` for the check, which works where `.length` should. I'll add it to my answer and let you decide.

Comment: @roysc That's interesting because internally `empty` is using `.length` too, but for some reason doesn't trigger the bug.